# How to get a button side to an image

Tags: javascript, css, html, styling

I have a page in which i want to display the button just side to an image ,therefore it looks like image button and so an as a loop where the implies to download but i am not good at css and I tried as below but it does not fix to my requirement.Can any one please adjust my code.Thanks in advance.

```
<section id="content" class="smPaddingTop60">
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="nobottommargin">
                <div> 
                    <div class="pressImg col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <img img-cache  ng-src="images/press/launchad_winners.jpg" onError="this.src='images/noimage.png';" alt="launchpad_winners">
                    </div>
                    <button class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 btn btn-success" data-ng-click="closePotentialModel()">
                        <a target="_BLANK" href="https://app.hubspot.com/meetings/troy-martin"><span style="color:white;">Schedule a Meeting</span></a>
                    </button>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="imgContainer">
                        <img img-cache class="image_fade mgnbtm" ng-src="images/press/logo.jpg" onError="this.src='images/noimage.png';" alt="launchpad_winners">
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="imgContainer">
                        <img img-cache  ng-src="images/press/xpertdox_logo_text.jpg" onError="this.src='images/noimage.png';" alt="launchpad_winners">
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="imgContainer">
                        <img img-cache class="image_fade mgnbtm" ng-src="images/press/logo_text_blue.jpg" onError="this.src='images/noimage.png';" alt="launchpad_winners">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have provided us literally no CSS at all.

Comment: I am not using n=any css i want these images one after the other as a list.

Comment: If you don’t want to use any CSS the only way to make a list is, well, to actually make a list (with `ul` or `ol`).

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
img.the-image-class + .the-button-class {
   display: block;
   margin-top: -20px; /* to move button 20px above from original position */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [output](https://jsfiddle.net/axpet0p4/22/) i think html was not formatted well.

```
<section id="content" class="smPaddingTop60">
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="pressImg col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <img img-cache  ng-src="images/press/launchad_winners.jpg" onError="this.src='images/noimage.png';" alt="launchpad_winners">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 ">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-ng-click="closePotentialModel()">
                        <a target="_BLANK" href="https://app.hubspot.com/meetings/troy-martin"><span style="color:white;">Schedule a Meeting</span></a>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="imgContainer">
                <img img-cache class="image_fade mgnbtm" ng-src="images/press/logo.jpg" onError="this.src='images/noimage.png';" alt="launchpad_winners">
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="imgContainer">
                <img img-cache  ng-src="images/press/xpertdox_logo_text.jpg" onError="this.src='images/noimage.png';" alt="launchpad_winners">
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="imgContainer">
                <img img-cache class="image_fade mgnbtm" ng-src="images/press/logo_text_blue.jpg" onError="this.src='images/noimage.png';" alt="launchpad_winners">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
May be like this,

<section id="content" class="smPaddingTop60">
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="nobottommargin">
                <div class="clearfix"> 
                    <div class="pressImg col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <img img-cache  ng-src="images/press/launchad_winners.jpg" onError="this.src='images/noimage.png';" alt="launchpad_winners">

                    </div>
                    <button class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 btn btn-success" data-ng-click="closePotentialModel()">
                        <a target="_BLANK" href="https://app.hubspot.com/meetings/troy-martin"><span style="color:white;">Schedule a Meeting</span></a>
                    </button>
                   </div> 
                    <hr>
                    <div class="imgContainer">
                        <img img-cache class="image_fade mgnbtm" ng-src="images/press/logo.jpg" onError="this.src='images/noimage.png';" alt="launchpad_winners">

                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="imgContainer">
                        <img img-cache  ng-src="images/press/xpertdox_logo_text.jpg" onError="this.src='images/noimage.png';" alt="launchpad_winners" >
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="imgContainer">
                        <img img-cache class="image_fade mgnbtm" ng-src="images/press/logo_text_blue.jpg" onError="this.src='images/noimage.png';" alt="launchpad_winners" >
                    </div>




            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```